# jQuery & set cookies using Ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I am setting cookies using jquery+jquery cookie.

```
jQuery.cookie('status', 'active', {expires: 1, path: '/'});
```

Now how can I set this cookie using AJAX? regarless of jquery cookie, how would you set a cookie using ajax in jquery, anyone has any idea.

Links to original question ([PHP & JQuery passing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776850/php-jquery-passing-variables/18776984))

**update**

So I am making the AJAX request like so in my jquery code

```
$.ajax({
    url:  "script.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: { status: active}
    });
```

And in my php I am processing it like;

```
if($_GET['status']!='')
{
    setcookie("status", $_GET['status'], time()+3600);
}
```

but nothing is happening, no cookie is being set. can anyone see the problem,

Comment: what do you mean using AJAX? what do you need AJAX for?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cookies on the server the same you would for a normal page request. Just look into your server side language of choice's way of setting cookies. Ajax requests are nothing more than normal http requests. When the response gets back to the server the cookies will be set set by the browser.

PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: However, I need to set the cookie based on a jquery conditional

Comment: Ok, just pass a boolean in your Jquery ajax request that you can evaluate on the server. Either a query string param or a post parameter

Comment: ive never used ajax before, i dont know how to set the cookie with the help of ajax, im learning how to program

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.passer-by.net/2011/09/18/how-to-set-get-cookie-via-ajax/